# hide/reveal input fields asp

Tags: javascript, asp.net, hide

I'm trying to create a web form where users can enter more than one qualification, I want to create an add more details button and am trying to do that by hiding some of the input fields which will then be revealed when a button is clicked, what is the best way of doing this, this is my asp code so far

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="four">
   <h2>Qualifications</h2>
   <br />
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQualSubject" AssociatedControlID="ddlQualSubject" CssClass="Emlabel"> Qualification Subject/Code: </asp:Label><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQualSubject" runat="server" CssClass="Eminput"/>
   <br />
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQualYear" AssociatedControlID="txtQualYear" CssClass="Emlabel"> Qualification Year: </asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtQualYear" runat="server" CssClass="Eminput" />
   <br />
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQualGrade" AssociatedControlID="txtQualGrade" CssClass="Emlabel"> Qualification Grade: </asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtQualGrade" runat="server" CssClass="Eminput" /><br />
   <br />
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQualSubject2" AssociatedControlID="ddlQualSubject2" CssClass="Emlabel"> Qualification Subject/Code: </asp:Label><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQualSubject2" runat="server" CssClass="Eminput"/>
   <br />
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQualYear2" AssociatedControlID="txtQualYear2" CssClass="Emlabel"> Qualification Year: </asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtQualYear2" runat="server" CssClass="Eminput" />
   <br />
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQualGrade2" AssociatedControlID="txtQualGrade2" CssClass="Emlabel"> Qualification Grade: </asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtQualGrade2" runat="server" CssClass="Eminput" />
   <br />
   <br />
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQualSubject3" AssociatedControlID="ddlQualSubject3" CssClass="Emlabel"> Qualification Subject/Code: </asp:Label><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQualSubject3" runat="server" CssClass="Eminput"/>
   <br />
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQualYear3" AssociatedControlID="txtQualYear3" CssClass="Emlabel"> Qualification Year: </asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtQualYear3" runat="server" CssClass="Eminput" />
   <br />
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQualGrade3" AssociatedControlID="txtQualGrade3" CssClass="Emlabel"> Qualification Grade: </asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtQualGrade3" runat="server" CssClass="Eminput" />
   <br />
   <br />
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQualSubject4" AssociatedControlID="ddlQualSubject4" CssClass="Emlabel"> Qualification Subject/Code: </asp:Label><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQualSubject4" runat="server" CssClass="Eminput"/>
   <br />
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQualYear4" AssociatedControlID="txtQualYear4" CssClass="Emlabel"> Qualification Year: </asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtQualYear4" runat="server" CssClass="Eminput" />
   <br />
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQualGrade4" AssociatedControlID="txtQualGrade4" CssClass="Emlabel"> Qualification Grade: </asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtQualGrade4" runat="server" CssClass="Eminput" />
   <br />
</div>
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Bootstrap Collapse is your choice:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

You can use it to show/hide the optional.

Comment: This was very useful and something I haven't thought of using it almost works but for some reason causes my application to POST

Comment: Did you check you button type is not submit?
Or you element is <a> tag, you should modify href to  "#" or "javascript:void(0)"

Comment: Yeah I've pretty much copy and pasted it from the site and then adjusted it so definitely no submit

Comment: Solved it, apparently needs to be explicitly stated to be button rather or it could be assumed a submit button, cheers for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add Css style attribute `display:none` and remove it after button is clicked